# Stripe / ngx-stripe: how to display saved payment method

Tags: angular, stripe-payments

I am presenting a `ngx-stripe-card` element for a saved Stripe customer.
After fetching the saved payment methods for that customer (by way of server-side code) I would want to update the UI with the saved card info, including the last four digits of the card.

I am trying to find a method on `StripeCardComponent` that will accept the information just retrieved...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Stripe (or Stripe.js) does not have a component to display a saved card. You have to create your own UI (like using labels) to show the PaymentMethod ID and other customer-identifiable information, like the card's last4 digits, brand (e.g. `visa`), the expiry info.

It looks like `StripeCardComponent` is a component for collecting card details (basically cardElement) so that doesn't support prefilling attached card info, it only collects card info.